# image upload with "post" in nodejs with request module

Tags: node.js

How do we upload an image received form the mobile app to another server using the request module in nodejs?

I have tried using the multipart module to extract the file and send it in formData attribute with the request module (post method). This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use following code, it has been tested in express. you can modify it according to your requirement

```
var path = require('path');
var util = require('util');
if (req.files.profile_image !== undefined) {
    var file = req.files.profile_image;
    var tmp_path = file.path;
    var fileName = file.name;
    var milliseconds = new Date().getTime();
    var file_ext = fileName.substr((Math.max(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".")) || Infinity) + 1);
    var newFileName = requestedUser + '_' + milliseconds + '.' + file_ext;
    var pathToFile = require('path').dirname(require.main.filename);
    var mainPath = path.dirname(pathToFile)
    var target_path = path.join(mainPath, 'public/uploads/users', newFileName);
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(tmp_path)
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(target_path);
    util.pump(readStream, writeStream, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            //handle error
        } else {

            //successfully uploaded
        }
    });

} else {
    //file not recieved
}
```

Thanks